# Silent read illegal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to use silent reading in a Bash script in Ubuntu 22.04:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sensitive_input() {
    read -rsp "${1}: " value
    echo "$value"
}

x=$(sensitive_input "Password: ")
```

And I get: `read: Illegal option -s`

If I try `read -rsp "test: " value` on terminal, it works.

Why it is working like that? What is it wrong in the shell script?

Comment: As an aside, you double-dipped the colon. Don't include it in the prompt string AND hardcode it in the function.

Comment: It's not _bash_ "working like that". For this to happen you're starting your script with `sh`, which is not bash. (That can happen a few ways: explicitly, with `sh scriptname` is one way to avoid the shebang; failing to set permissions to make an `execv()` succeed can also result in undefined behavior when running a script from other shells, which in some but not all cases will include the shebang being ignored)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you calling your script?

I'm guessing you're doing something like:

```
$ sh script_name
```

This will cause the script to run under the `sh` shell which in my `Ubuntu 22.04` env is actually `dash` and `dash` does not support the `-s` option to `read`. We can see this in the following:

```
#### run on Ubuntu 22.04; my default shell is bash

$ man sh                            # brings up the man page for dash

$ read -rsp "Password: " value      # run under bash
Password:                           # success
                         

$ sh                                # switch from bash to sh
$ read -rsp "Password: " value
sh: 1: read: Illegal option -s      # error

$ exit                              # switch back to bash

$ dash                              # explicitly switch to dash
$ read -rsp "Password: " value
dash: 1: read: Illegal option -s    # error
```

To insure your script utilizes the shell listed in the shebang:

```
#### following works as desired regardless of the command line shell (bash, sh, dash)

$ chmod +x script_name              # insure script is executable (per Ted Lyngmo comment)
$ ./script_name                     # let OS determine shell from shebang
Password:                           # success
```

Comment: Yes. I found that the problem was `dash`, because I was calling the script with `sh`. Launching it with `bash script.sh` it worked. I forgot to publish the solution.